# Sorting one list to match another in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Suppose I have these lists:

```
ids = [4, 3, 7, 8]
objects = [
             {"id": 7, "text": "are"},
             {"id": 3, "text": "how"},
             {"id": 8, "text": "you"},
             {"id": 4, "text": "hello"}
          ]
```

How can I sort the `objects` so the order of their ids matches `ids`? I.e. to get this result:

```
objects = [
             {"id": 4, "text": "hello"},
             {"id": 3, "text": "how"},
             {"id": 7, "text": "are"},
             {"id": 8, "text": "you"}
          ]
```

Comment: Note that the answers assume 'id' is some unique property among the objects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
object_map = {o['id']: o for o in objects}
objects = [object_map[id] for id in ids]
```

Comment: I think I would factor the dict-comp out so you're not doing it over and over again.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [25]: idmap = dict((id,pos) for pos,id in enumerate(ids))

In [26]: sorted(objects, key=lambda x:idmap[x['id']])
Out[26]: 
[{'id': 4, 'text': 'hello'},
 {'id': 3, 'text': 'how'},
 {'id': 7, 'text': 'are'},
 {'id': 8, 'text': 'you'}]
```

Comment: Strangely almost char for char what I had in my text editor ;)

Comment: @JonClements: We clearly spend far too much time on this site ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ids = [4,3,7,8]
>>> id_orders = {}
>>> for i,id in enumerate(ids):
...     id_orders[id] = i
... 
>>> id_orders
{8: 3, 3: 1, 4: 0, 7: 2}
>>> 
>>> sorted(objs, key=lambda x: id_orders[x['id']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` with a custom `key` function which simply gets `index` from `ids`:

```
sorted(objects, key=lambda x: ids.index(x['id']))
```

(Inspired by [NPE’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15880997/711006).)

Comment: Ah yeah this is a much nicer answer.

Comment: Actually I take that back, this `.index()` gives this suboptimal complexity.